# Python ModBus Programming Protocol3 System

Tags: python-3.x

I have very low knowledge about ModBus controllers, I have a Protocol3 Controller System http://www.despatch.com/protocol3.aspx that I want to control using a Python GUI.

I know that I can control the Protocol3 via ModBus. My Protocol3 has an ethernet port and I can talk with the controller using their software, however, controller software is very limited and I want to take full control using Python.

Does anyone have a clue of how the ModBus works? Do I have to buy an ModBus controller to set is as Master and set my Protocol3 as Slave?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have find an article that help me out to understand and write a pice of software to control my Despatch Protocol-3 ModBus Module. 
https://github.com/sourceperl/pyModbusTCP using Python Module "PyModBusTCP" http://pymodbustcp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ and Protocol3 programming guide.

I think I can close now this topic.

Thanks all for stop by.